# Why doesn’t setting the “disabled” property of a <link> tag via JavaScript work in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I am implementing a JavaScript function that enables/disables two CSS file of a website:

```
function switch_style ()
{
    var i, link_tag ;
    for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link"); i < link_tag.length ; i++ ) 
    {
        if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf( "stylesheet" ) != -1) && link_tag[i].title) 
        {
            if(link_tag[i].title == "normal")
            {
                link_tag[i].disabled = true;
            }
            else if (link_tag[i].title == "contrast")
            {
                link_tag[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    set_cookie( style_cookie_name, "contrast", style_cookie_duration );
}
```

As you can see, I enable or disable a link tag. This works in all browsers but not in IE8.

Is there a known reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're toggling the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/link#Attributes) property of `link` elements. As said on MDC,

> [t]his attribute is non-standard and
>   only used by some Microsoft browsers
>   and **must not be used by authors**.
>   To achieve its effect, use one of the
>   following techniques:
>
> - If the `disabled` attribute has been added directly to the page, do not
>     include the `<link>` element instead;
> - If the `disabled` attribute has been added via scripting, remove it from
>     the DOM via scripting.

To remove a `link` element from the DOM, use [`element.removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild).

Just a stupid example: if you want to remove the first `link` element on a page, just enter this JavaScript function in your browser's location bar:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];a.removeChild(a.getElementsByTagName('link')[0])})();
```

(I just tried it on SO, looked funny :)

Answer (score 0):

what if you use `removeAttribute('disabled')` instead of setting it to false?